# Array within array as single associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having array within array values as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Floor] => Floor-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Flat] => Flat A2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Area] => Balcony,
                )

        )
)
```

I need to make it as single associative array as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
             [Floor] => Floor-1
             [Flat] => Flat A2
             [Area] => Balcony,
        )
)
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: That's nice. So what have you done to try to achieve this? Does the first array _always_ have just one array inside of it? Are keys ever repeated in the inner array?

Comment: I can't access array within array values in future. If I get the output as required value, I can fetch it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example should help you.

```
<?php


$arr = array(
    array(
        'floor'=>'Floor-1'
        ),
    array(
        'Flat'=>'Flat A2'
        ),
    array(
        'Area'=>'Balcony,'
        ),
    );



$final_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $arr1) {

    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
        $final_array[$key] = $value;
    }

}


?>
```

> Output will be

```
 Array
    (
        [floor] => Floor-1
        [Flat] => Flat A2
        [Area] => Balcony,
    )
```

Here we have created an empty array called as `$final_array` we will append this array by using `foreach` loop.

> Remember, if you have a same array key then the last value will overwrite like below.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        'floor'=>'Floor-1',
        'floor'=>'Floor-2',
        ),
    array(
        'Flat'=>'Flat A2'
        ),
    array(
        'Area'=>'Balcony,'
        ),

     array(
        'Area'=>'Balcony2,'
        ),
    );



$final_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $arr1) {

    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
        $final_array[$key] = $value;
    }

}


?>
```

> Now, output will be

```
Array
(
    [floor] => Floor-2
    [Flat] => Flat A2
    [Area] => Balcony2,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        [
            'foo' => 'big'
        ],
        [
            'bar' => 'fat'
        ],
        [
            'baz' => 'mamma'
        ]
    ]
];

$merged[0] = array_reduce($array[0], function($carry, $item) {
    return array_merge((array) $carry, $item);
});

var_export($merged);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'foo' => 'big',
    'bar' => 'fat',
    'baz' => 'mamma',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This single line code is enough to do this

```
$newArr = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$dataArr); ///where $dataArr is your array..
```

call_user_func_array will call a callback function with array of parameters and array_merge will merge all these parameters in single array read more about [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Example code:

```
<?php 
$dataArr = array(
                array(
                    'Floor'=>'Floor-1'
                    ),
                array(
                    'Flat'=>'Flat A2'
                    ),
                array(
                    'Area'=>'Balcony,'
                    ),
            );
$newArr = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$dataArr);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArr);
?>
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [Floor] => Floor-1
    [Flat] => Flat A2
    [Area] => Balcony,
)
```